# SQL put average per month in columns side by side

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two queries that calculates the average between an old discount and new discount. I am calculating avergages per month and I would like to know how I can put these values side-by-side columns:

Here is my query:

```
Select AVG(ABS(NewDiscount - OldDiscount)) AS [Average Discount Change in February]
From DiscountChange
where MONTH(ChangeDate) = 2
and YEAR(ChangeDate) = 2021

Select AVG(ABS(NewDiscount - OldDiscount)) AS [Average Discount Change in January]
From DiscountChange
where MONTH(ChangeDate) = 1
and YEAR(ChangeDate) = 2021
```

The output I would like to get is:

```
[Average Discount Change in February] | [Average Discount Change in January]
```

Here's the schema of the DiscountChange table:

```
Create Table DiscountChange
(
    DiscountChangeId Decimal(12) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    , CouponId Decimal(12) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Coupon(CouponId)
    , OldDiscount MONEY NOT NULL
    , NewDiscount MONEY NOT NULL
    , ChangeDate DATE NOT NULL 
)
```

How do I modify my query to achieve the output as above?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
Select AVG(CASE WHEN MONTH(ChangeDate) = 1 THEN ABS(NewDiscount - OldDiscount) END),
       AVG(CASE WHEN MONTH(ChangeDate) = 2 THEN ABS(NewDiscount - OldDiscount) END)      
From DiscountChange
where ChangeDate >= '2021-01-01' AND
      ChangeDate < '2021-03-01'
```